# Selenium Shadow dom inside a shadow dom

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the text but get an error.

[This is the HTML Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKNsy.png)

This is the Xpath:

```
/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[7]/div/div[2]/bc-data-grid//div/div[2]/set-class[3]/div[2]/a/text-binding
```

I tried all things listed here, I don't have much experience with HTML so I pretty much copy-paste and change the xpath, I may miss something.

[Selenium "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException" when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Thanks for your help!

**Edit**: I realized that there is a Shadow dom inside a shadow dom, I am unable to extract the text.

[HTML Code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7R3L.png)
I know you don't like pic of code, but I cant copy all elemnts.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Your element is placed in `shadow root`, that means, that to get it, you need to get it's host first, go inside `shadowRoot` property and get element inside it or just get property `textContent`.

I don't know your full html structure, but in you case host has tag `text-binding`.

Let's try to construct selector.

1. Container has unique selector `#_grid`
2. On next level you have different rows. Next level would be `.row`
3. As far as you need only short name, next level selector would be `_cell.symbol`
4. And shadow-root host has selector `text-binding`

So, possible `CSS SELECTOR` would be `#_grid [role=row] ._cell.symbol text-binding`.

Then you execute JS script on shadow host element.

**UPD**

As far as you have on new provided screen shadow-root in shadow-root, you should access first shadow root, and from it's root access second.
If you need loop - you should define cell locator with class `symbolName`, it's the name cell of your stock.

Also, be aware that table is loaded async, and trigger is scrolling.
So to get all stocks, you need to implement continuous scroll through your table.

```py
url = "https://www.barchart.com/stocks/indices/sp/sp500?page=all"
driver.get(url)
table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'bc-data-grid[id*=table-guid]')))
# there should be continuous scroll to bottom of the table
table_content = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector("#_root")', table)
shadow_root_hosts = table_content.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#_grid [role=row] ._cell.symbol text-binding')
for host in shadow_root_hosts:
    text = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot.textContent', host)
    print(text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! What should it look like if I want to enter the next row or column? or better if I can use XPath inside of ccs_selector?

Comment: For selecting row with index `shadow_root_host` would be `shadow_root_host = table_content.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#_grid .row data-binding')[i]`, where i is index of row. 
`

Comment: It brings back, `IndexError: list index out of range`, do you know why? and Thank you for your help!

Comment: please, provide your whole DOM, so it would be possible to help. It should be ok if you loop by range of `table_content.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#_grid .row data-binding')`.

Comment: [link](https://www.barchart.com/stocks/indices/sp/sp500?page=all) My goal is to get the data provided.

Comment: @DanPress see updated snippet.